# PHP Echo $info's at descending order

Tags: php, mysql, database

Okay, so I have my table in my database named 'posts'

There are 6 fields

```
postid, title, message, date, time, day
```

Whenever I print out every rows, it prints out ascending-ly?

**TABLE**

**postid** | **title** | **message**

00001 | ........ | ........

00002 | ........ | ........

00003 | ........ | ........

And when I print out, it is like

```
00001, ..., ...
00002, ..., ...
00003, ..., ...
```

But I want

```
0003, ..., ...
0002, ..., ...
0001, ..., ...
```

Is there a way to do that? I can't find it in google so... Anyways, thank in advance :)

Comment: Order the query descending.

Comment: Is it important that you only get a 4 character total or is that just a mistake you made?

Comment: You couldn't find it in Google? I just tried "mysql descending order", and the first page of results were all relevant.

Comment: Maybe he wants to trim the result as @Bono said...! but if that's a typo you only need to append `orderby postid desc` to the query

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT `postid`, `title`, `message`, `date`, `time`, `day`
FROM `table1`
ORDER BY `postid` DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
select reverse(substr(reverse(postid), 1, 4)) as postid, title, message, date, time, day from posts order by postid desc;
```

Assuming you wanted the output in 4 digits and not 5

Answer (score 0):

Append this to your query:

```
ORDER BY `postid` DESC
```

It will order the results in descending order rather than ascending.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
SELECT `postid`, `title`, `message`, `date`, `time`, `day`
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY `postid` DESC;
```

You can also

```
SELECT CONCAT(`postid`, ',', `title`, ',',  `message`, ',', `date`, ',', `time`, ',', `day`)
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY `postid` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the query like, `SELECT postid, title, message, date, time, day FROM`table`ORDER BY`postid`DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ORDER BY function.

SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY `postid` DESC

The DESC keyword just reverses the order.